# Print html code with angular2

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to print a button in html passing it as a parameter in angular2 but angular2 never translate it.

*modal.component.ts*

```
this.footer = `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`
```

*modal.component.html*

```
<div class="modal-footer" [innerHTML]="footer"></div>
```

*output html*

```
<div class="modal-footer" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="Close">Close</div>
```

Comment: I think you will not be able to make the button work at all if you do it like that.. angular needs to "compile" it somehow.. Why not put it inside the div? use ngif or something ?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I have to find a way to pass the buttons of modal as a parameter so that I can adjudicate the parameters in the function that calls the modal

Answer (score 2):

Should be `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML`. It is case sensitive.

For example :

```
<div class="modal-footer" [innerHtml]="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I tried but it does not change the result.
I also forgot to mention that if I pass as a parameter "<b> body </b>" it keeps it right.